# Java: Why am I getting null in the output?

Tags: java

```
public class A{

   TreeMap<String, Double> sortedPairList;
   HashMap<String, Double> PairList = new HashMap<String, Double>();

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   A p = new A();

    p.PairList.put("a00", 0.3920948902348);
    p.PairList.put("a01", 0.4920948902348);
    p.PairList.put("a02", 0.3420948902348);
    p.PairList.put("a03", 0.5920948902348);
    p.PairList.put("a04", 0.6720948902348);
    p.PairList.put("a05", 0.3940948902348);
    p.PairList.put("a06", 0.3920948902348);
    p.PairList.put("a07", 0.9920948902348);
    p.PairList.put("a08", 0.6920948902348);
    p.PairList.put("a09", 0.7920948902348);
    p.PairList.put("a10", 0.8820948902348);
    p.PairList.put("a11", 0.1220948902348);
    p.PairList.put("a12", 0.1920948902348);
    p.PairList.put("a13", 0.4520948902348);
    p.PairList.put("a14", 0.3434948902348);
    p.PairList.put("a15", 0.5690948902348);
    p.PairList.put("a16", 0.5920948902348);
    p.PairList.put("a17", 0.8920948902348);
    p.PairList.put("a18", 0.920948902348);
    p.PairList.put("a19", 0.9820948902348);
    p.PairList.put("a20", 0.1920948902348);
    p.PairList.put("a21", 0.5920948902348);
    p.PairList.put("a22", 0.3920948902348);
    p.PairList.put("a23", 0.3920948902348);

    p.sortPairList(p.PairList) ;

    for(String s : p.sortedPairList.keySet() ){
         System.out.println("key:: value: " + s + "  ::"+p.sortedPairList.get(s));
    }

}//end of main


public void sortPairList(HashMap<String, Double> pairlist) {
    ValueComparator comp = new ValueComparator(pairlist);

    sortedPairList = new TreeMap<String, Double>(comp);

    sortedPairList.putAll(pairlist);


}// end of sortedPredicatePairList

class ValueComparator implements Comparator<Object> {

    Map<String, Double> temp;

    public ValueComparator(Map<String, Double> base) {
        this.temp = base;
    }

    public int compare(Object p1, Object p2) {

        if ((Double) temp.get(p1) < (Double) temp.get(p2)) {
            return 1;
        } else if ((Double) temp.get(p1) == (Double) temp.get(p2)) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }

    }
}// end of class ValueComparator
}//end of classA
```

*The output I am getting is the following, why I am getting nulls in the values which are repeated :***

key:: value: a07 ::0.9920948902348

key:: value: a19 ::0.9820948902348

key:: value: a18 ::0.920948902348

key:: value: a17 ::0.8920948902348

key:: value: a10 ::0.8820948902348

key:: value: a09 ::0.7920948902348

key:: value: a08 ::0.6920948902348

key:: value: a04 ::0.6720948902348

key:: value: a03 ::0.5920948902348

**key:: value: a21 ::null**

**key:: value: a16 ::null**

key:: value: a15 ::0.5690948902348

key:: value: a01 ::0.4920948902348

key:: value: a13 ::0.4520948902348

key:: value: a05 ::0.3940948902348

key:: value: a06 ::0.3920948902348

key:: value: a23 ::0.3920948902348

key:: value: a22 ::0.3920948902348

**key:: value: a00 ::null**

key:: value: a14 ::0.3434948902348

key:: value: a02 ::0.3420948902348

key:: value: a12 ::0.1920948902348

**key:: value: a20 ::null**

key:: value: a11 ::0.1220948902348

Answer (score 3):

From [Tree Map API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html):

Note that the ordering maintained by a sorted map (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if this sorted map is to correctly implement the Map interface. (See Comparable or Comparator for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so because the Map interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a map performs all key comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two keys that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the sorted map, equal.

Your ValueComparator is definately not consistent with equals.

Somehow `p.sortedPairList.keySet()` contains keys that are "equal" according to your "ValueComparator", but you got `null` for duplicate keys.

Comment: But I am not able to see the bug in my comparator, please tell e specifically what is wrong with the comparator code?

Comment: Look at the link to the Tree Map API, and read carefully what means "Compare() inconsistent with Equals()". In two words, your keys in TreeMap are "equal" by ValueComparator.compare() method, but not equal by String.equals() method

Answer (score 2):

Declare `PairList` like this:

```
HashMap<String, Double> PairList = new HashMap<String, Double>();
```

And change your `ValueComparator#compare` method to:

```
public int compare(Object p1, Object p2) {
   return temp.get(p1).compareTo(temp.get(p2));
}
```

**Update** As per your comments use following `compare` method to get all 24 elements in ascending order:

```
public int compare(String p1, String p2) {
    if (temp.get(p1).doubleValue() < temp.get(p2).doubleValue())
        return 1;
    else if (temp.get(p1).doubleValue() == temp.get(p2).doubleValue())
        return p1.compareTo(p2);
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: `return temp.get(p1).compareTo(temp.get(p2));` gives me **descending** order.

Comment: But now this is giving another problem, I am not getting the duplicate values, only single value is being printed.

Comment: Its printing only 18 key-value pair instead of 24

Comment: Please check the code in **Update** section above to get all 24 elements in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is in your comparator.

In java you cannot compare objects using `==` operator. This operator does what you are expecting. So, to compare values of the doubles that you hold in your map you have to call `doubleValue()`. Here is my version of your comparator that works correctly.

```
    public int compare(Object p1, Object p2) {

        if (temp.get(p1).doubleValue() < temp.get(p2).doubleValue()) {
            return 1;
        } else if (temp.get(p1).doubleValue() == temp.get(p2).doubleValue()) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are comparing in your Comparator with the `==` sign. Replace that with the `equals()` method and it should work:

```
 public int compare(Object p1, Object p2) {

            if ((Double) temp.get(p1) < (Double) temp.get(p2)) {
                return 1;
            } else if (((Double) temp.get(p1)).equals((Double) temp.get(p2))) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }

        }
```

Comment: But now this is giving another problem, I am not getting the duplicate values, only single value is being printed.
Its printing only 18 key-value pair instead of 24